# Acumatica - sitemap item does not show in modern UI

Tags: acumatica

I just added a Sales Commissions report to sitemap and it shows in classic UI but not in modern UI. When I search for it in modern UI, result returns nothing. How my sitemap node looks like in project.xml:

```
<SiteMapNode>
    <data-set>
        <relations format-version="3" relations-version="20160101" main-table="SiteMap">
            <link from="MUIScreen (NodeID)" to="SiteMap (NodeID)" />
            <link from="MUIWorkspace (WorkspaceID)" to="MUIScreen (WorkspaceID)" type="FromMaster" linkname="workspaceToScreen" split-location="yes" updateable="True" />
            <link from="MUISubcategory (SubcategoryID)" to="MUIScreen (SubcategoryID)" type="FromMaster" updateable="True" />
            <link from="MUITile (ScreenID)" to="SiteMap (ScreenID)" />
            <link from="MUIWorkspace (WorkspaceID)" to="MUITile (WorkspaceID)" type="FromMaster" linkname="workspaceToTile" split-location="yes" updateable="True" />
            <link from="MUIArea (AreaID)" to="MUIWorkspace (AreaID)" type="FromMaster" updateable="True" />
            <link from="MUIPinnedScreen (NodeID, WorkspaceID)" to="MUIScreen (NodeID, WorkspaceID)" type="WeakIfEmpty" isEmpty="Username" />
            <link from="MUIFavoriteWorkspace (WorkspaceID)" to="MUIWorkspace (WorkspaceID)" type="WeakIfEmpty" isEmpty="Username" />
        </relations>
        <layout>
            <table name="SiteMap">
                <table name="MUIScreen" uplink="(NodeID) = (NodeID)">
                    <table name="MUIPinnedScreen" uplink="(NodeID, WorkspaceID) = (NodeID, WorkspaceID)" />
                </table>
                <table name="MUITile" uplink="(ScreenID) = (ScreenID)" />
            </table>
            <table name="MUIWorkspace">
                <table name="MUIFavoriteWorkspace" uplink="(WorkspaceID) = (WorkspaceID)" />
            </table>
            <table name="MUISubcategory" />
            <table name="MUIArea" />
        </layout>
        <data>
            <SiteMap>
                <row Position="1.5" Title="Sales Commissions" Url="~/Frames/ReportLauncher.aspx?ID=SO646000.rpx" Expanded="0" IsFolder="0" ScreenID="SO646000" NodeID="972cf181-504a-4df7-88d1-c4cb1a0c93d4" ParentID="85e0f6b3-8ae8-43aa-ad7b-ea4d4d5f381e" />
            </SiteMap>
        </data>
    </data-set>
</SiteMapNode>
```

And a screenshot of my site map directory:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wp2xWqdx-0lbGE7xfDuD6bhtLrK1-I7i

Any ideas what might be happening? I tried recreating site map entry several times and still nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add it to the work space after adding to the sitemap. Just because you add it to the sitemap does not automatically add it to the new UI.

The help articles should help to walk you through editing the new UI. Here is an article that might help:

[To Add a Link to a Workspace](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(4))/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=dd2b6435-fe00-4c87-9258-16d3445d1410)

More help...

[Customizing the Modern User Interface](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(3))/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=774107f8-a149-4676-9c78-0c884edd19cb)

[Workspaces in the Modern UI](https://help.acumatica.com/Wiki/(W(1))/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=51c2588f-6596-4091-9545-1d6fe1447303)

**Edit:** If you already added the sitemap to your customization and later add the entry to a workspace, you need to update the sitemap entry in your customization project by reloading from the database (option under sitemap).

Comment: Thanks again Brendan. Instructions from first link worked well. Any way to include this into customization package so the client doesn't have to do it themselves?

Comment: yes once you add it to the workspace you can update your customization package. Either add the sitemap entry if not already or reload from database. Note that on older versions do not load the sitemap correctly. I dont remember which version this was fixed in so if not working just remove the sitemap from your customization package and re-add. We distribute the sitemaps and the work spaces work just fine with our changes.