# How to deploy custom menu items to the new UI

Tags: acumatica

We have custom screens that we've added to a site map and deploy through a customization package - but it doesn't seem to add anything to the new UI.  Is there any documented procedure to add custom screens and reports to the new UI and have a customization package deploy this to a new site?

Answer (score 1):

There is documentation at [help.acumatica.com](https://help.acumatica.com).

To start I would look here: [Customizing the Modern User Interface](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(3))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=774107f8-a149-4676-9c78-0c884edd19cb)

This question is similar to this answered post: [Acumatica - sitemap item does not show in modern UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48602332/acumatica-sitemap-item-does-not-show-in-modern-ui)

Comment: Adding an entry to the sitemap doesn't know which workspace to add it to since they are not directly connected. We have over 50 pages/reports in customization package so there was a little time spent upgrading our package to the new UI. Same sitemap entries will work for 2017R2 & 2018R1 so just do once in 2017R2 should work.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'workspace'.  Are there multiple UI workspaces per login to a company?  I don't understand 'sitemap doesn't know which workspace to add it to'...  How is there more than one UI to add these sitemap entries to?

All I'm looking to do is the same thing the original UI would do - namely, allow the customization package to add items to the menu through publication.  Is this doable or not?

Comment: Yes it is possible through a customization package. To make sure the entries show up under the new UI you must first add the sitemap links to the related workspace (the new UI container for the links). Starting here https://help.acumatica.com/(W(3))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=774107f8-a149-4676-9c78-0c884edd19cb should help to understand the connected components. After you add the entry to the workspace you will add the sitemap to your customization project (or update from database). And then you can distribute the package to other instances.