# Acumatica Report Not Showing in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I recently just got into Acumatica Report Designer. I have followed a quick tutorial I had found at https://www.timrodman.com/building-your-first-report-in-acumatica-report-designer/, but when I put my report into my Local instance of Acumatica I can not see it. I can directly put the screen id in the URL, but if I search it nothing pops up. I changed all the access rights to granted for the report itself. I have all admin rights on my local instance. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are adding a Workspace and category for anything with Modern UI
Note the top report will show up on Inventory Workspace under the Physical Inventory Category
The bottom 4 reports are loaded on the server but not mapped to the ui so can be accessed in code via an action etc. but are not on the ui. And would be under hidden for security purposes

[Site Map Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gj9dR.png)

[Security View under hidden Workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uAjh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a picture of your sitemap?  My guess is that your URL is incorrect.

Comment: I added an image of the URL used for the report.

Comment: Are you saying you can't see it in the Acumatica menu?  Are you able to load the report if you put the screenid directly in the URL?

Comment: Yes, I can put the screen ID in manually and see the report; however, if I type the name of the report on the search bar or try to find it to add to the menu I cannot see it.

Comment: Ah I see, I actually misunderstood your problem.  I find that signing out and logging back in results in me being able to search for my report.  Good luck!

Comment: @C.J. Hope, it sounds like you're searching in Modern UI. You could test that hypothesis by switching to Classic UI in your profile and testing search again. From memory in Modern UI you need to add the report in a workspace before it's visible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48602332/acumatica-sitemap-item-does-not-show-in-modern-ui